# Combining an Excel IF Statement with VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup, if

I have the following if statement in Excel:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(AB2,AD:AD,1,0)=TRUE,1,0)
```

What I am trying to do is say the following:

"If the results of the `VLOOKUP` return any value other than "#N/A", take the value of 1, otherwise take the value of 0."

What it's currently doing is if there is a returned value from the `VLOOKUP`, it's returning 0.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Since there is no intention to actually use a returned value, it might be clearer to use a MATCH rather than VLOOKUP. That would the purpose of your formula clearer to others (or to you, later down the line). VLLOKUP fetches data; MATCH looks for a match and tells you where it is (or that it is not there). So IF(ISNA(MATCH(AB2,AD:AD,0),0,1) would seem to be what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(AB2,AD:AD,1,0)),0,1)
```

- `ISNA(VLOOKUP(AB2,AD:AD,1,0))`: returns TRUE is "#N/A", otherwise returns FALSE.